# ember-cli 0.2.1 - generated addon test cannot find mixin

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I have recently upgraded ember-cli 0.2.0 to 0.2.1 and I ran the following command to generate a mixin:

```
ember g mixin listener
```

The generate file was place in `addon/mixins/listener.js`.

The generated test looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ListenerMixin from '../../../mixins/listener';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';

module('ListenerMixin');

// Replace this with your real tests.
test('it works', function(assert) {
  var ListenerObject = Ember.Object.extend(ListenerMixin);
  var subject = ListenerObject.create();
  assert.ok(subject);
});
```

The test fails with the following error message:

> Could not find module `dummy/mixins/listener` imported from
>   `dummy/tests/unit/mixins/listener-test`

My mixins should be in `/addons/` and not `/app/`

What do I need to change for the tests to find the module?

When I upgraded from 0.2.0 to 0.2.1 I followed the docs for upgrading and ran all the steps in the docs

but this line:

```
ember init
```

Returned this error which I assume is something to do with it:

> Generating an addon in an existing ember-cli project is not supported.

Comment: The error you mentioned on init [was recently fixed](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/3622) but has not been released yet. Should be in the next version.

Comment: And [v0.2.2 is out with the fix](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v0.2.2)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue on Ember-CLI 0.2.3 and it appears the resolver still has a problem with Mixins that are part of an **addon**. I solved this by replacing Ember-CLI's default:

```
import MyMixin from '../../../mixins/my-mixin';
```

to ...

```
import MyMixin from '[addon-name]/mixins/my-mixin';
```

Works for me. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another mixin in the app tree, to be merged with the parent app's tree.

```
import ListenerMixin from 'addon-name/mixins/listener';

export default ListenerMixin;
```

and if you don't want that, you'll need to change this line: `module('ListenerMixin');` as that tries to find that module in the app tree.  You might also change line 2 to `import ListenerMixin from 'addon-name/mixins/listener';`

Answer (score 0):

This may be a known issue with `ember-cli@1.13.8` and is currently being investigated:
https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4633